# Git: fatal: fsync error on 'sha1 file': Bad file descriptor

Tags: windows, git

I'm using VS Code with Git - it's in portable location C:\_DEV\bin\git and is also added to Windows PATH so it works just fine with no remotes.

I have a OneDrive *_GIT* folder where I have some of my "remote" repositories, that sync between 2 devices (sometimes, I have it there mainly for backup purposes).

The error appears when I want to commit changes, only way to "fix" this issue is to restart the computer, so I'd like to find a way how to fix it properly. The problem is, it doesn't appear always and not for all repositories, it's pretty random.

I think it's because of sync from/to OneDrive. Is there a command I can run to fix the file descriptor? Or other way to prevent it?

```
git remote --verbose
git ls-tree -l HEAD -- a:\new\theme\assets\sass\main.scss
git show 97a333c5e7fce816dbb46a5c1235d69e61836726
git show HEAD:theme/assets/sass/main.scss
git add -A -- a:\new\theme\assets\sass\main.scss
fatal: fsync error on 'sha1 file': Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: The proper solution is not to store your Git repositories on network drives.  (I'm not trying to be snarky.  This is explicitly _not_ a supported scenario.)

Comment: But this is not a network drive, it's my local drive and it's synced to OneDrive cloud storage ..

Comment: I have the same problem when using a local drive mapped to virtual machine and GIT in that VM. Apparenlty it is caused by GIT, because I don't use VS Code.

Comment: I've also had the problem with this fails in `Visual Studio Code` while the main repository is open in another tool, like `Visual Studio 2019`. Try closing `Visual Studio 2019` and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Do you have a source for that @EdwardThomson? I have been unable to find any evidence that your claim is true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to @edward-thomson.
I had same problem on my PC, where i mapped a folder under my homedrive to E:

```
C:\Users\myuserid\E-Folder\SomeGitProject
```

by sharing the folder, so i could shortcut it to

```
E:\SomeGitProject
```

Solution was to use the full path in CMD or use the shortcut to homedrive from git bash:

```
~/E-Folder/SomeGitProject
```

I guess your A: likewise is a share, that you can access with a full path probably also located somewhere under your homedrive.

Comment: Thanks, after long testing I found no issue with OneDrive, but the problem was in folder mapped to drive as you suggested. So instead of having drives A B Y now I have folders A_DEV, B_DEV, Y_DEV, same functionality, just without sharing and drives..

Answer (score 9):

I am posting late to help others get to the solution faster than I did. The actual culprit was elusive, and I tried everything from re-installing GIT to creating new repositories.

This happened to me in windows and it was `due to a change in permissions in a parent folder` somewhere.

The solution was to simply `disconnect and remap the folder`.

Comment: yes, it's a problem when you map a drive. instead of mapping the drive, make it a special folder in My Computer so you have same quick access just without git issues

Comment: Same happened with me, the error message was `fatal: fsync error on 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor`  
Possible solution is to change ownership of the parent folder.

Comment: For context, my Hyper-V VM has a drive mapped to a host machine shared directory. Using the **exact same setup** (i.e. *SourceTree*, files stored on mapped drive, *BitBucket* account, etc.)... `RepositoryA` works without issue, and `RepositoryB` will generate a `fsync error` when I to stage files. **Solution:** disconnect & remap drive worked for me as well. Now both `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` work.

Comment: 5 minutes after my previous post, the `fsync error` re-appeared. I have a sneaking suspicion that it might be related to running *Visual Studio* and *SourceTree* at the same time on the same repository.  I have never had an issue with this in the past.

Comment: @Pressacco, that latest one was the issue for me (almost three years later). Or, more specifically in my case, one instance of VS2019 and one of VS2022 at the same time. I closed down VS2022, and the problem went away immediately.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this error a lot recently, and the above answers helped, but another thing that also seems to cause it is VS itself running.

Try closing VS, then doing a "Git Bash Here" from Explorer and using the command line only.

Once done you can then reopen VS.

Comment: I kept receiving the `fsync` error using from both *Visual Studio* and *Source Tree*.  As per @Whelkaholism suggestion, I closed both applications and created the commit via the *Git Bash*. It worked!  FYI - rather than stage one file at a time for the commit, this command helped: `git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`

Answer (score 2):

I also have mapped my root webspace as a drive.
This is no problem until files are watched (like with npm run watch).

Comment: yes that's possible. I develop with Prepros so the project folder is nonstop watched by it .. but I don't have these issues anymore. I've mapped my "www" folder as Custom Folder with ThisPCTweaker (it appears same as Downloads or Desktop in My Computer)

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. I just resolved this issue with the following steps:

1- Close Visual Code

2- Open project on git bash command line

3- Commit the code again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with visual studio 2017. My solution was to close visual studio, then open Visual studio CODE and merge the files there.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code works. A bit easier than disconnecting and re-mapping the folder (which also works).

Comment: maybe works for you, but definitely not for me :) that was the first thing I tried ...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. In my case the problem was low disk space. Hope this helps someone.