# Git error - fatal: fsync error on 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor

Tags: git, repo

I am working on a chat app using ReactJs and nodeJs. I have deployed it on herokuapp using the git and I'm building the application in Visual studio code.

When I tried to commit my changes, this error occurred and I'm not able to commit any changes due to this error.

Git log for the error:

```
$ git status -z -u
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
$ git rev-parse master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
$ git show :client/public/index.html
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
$ git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
$ git remote --verbose
$ git check-ignore -z --stdin
$ git add -A -- .
fatal: fsync error on 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor
$ git show :client/public/index.html
$ git status -z -u
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
$ git rev-parse master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
$ git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
$ git remote --verbose
$ git status -z -u
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
$ git rev-parse master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
$ git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
$ git remote --verbose
```

Comment: please if some one knows the answer feel free to answer i encountered the same problem

Answer (score 6):

I know this is two years old but I just experienced this error and Google brought me here - and then to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929881/git-fatal-fsync-error-on-sha1-file-bad-file-descriptor/51986318#51986318) which was the answer to my problem: the error occurs when your workspace is on a mapped drive and VS and/or Code is open.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of ownership/drive mapping issues mentioned in "[Git: fatal: fsync error on 'sha1 file': Bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929881/6309)", you can actually know what file is problematic.

When creating a loose object file, we didn't report the exact filename of the file we failed to `fsync`, even though the information was readily available, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit c4e707f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4e707f858813c097bd8b488baae07096aa280ad) (30 Mar 2022) by [Neeraj Singh (`neerajsi-msft`)](https://github.com/neerajsi-msft).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 98f6a3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98f6a3a35335d5d4b48df0088f2da0075e07f99c), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`object-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4e707f858813c097bd8b488baae07096aa280ad): pass filename to `fsync_or_die`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Neeraj Singh</sup>

> If we die while trying to fsync a loose object file, pass the *actual filename* we're trying to sync.
>
> This is likely to be more helpful for a user trying to diagnose the cause of the failure than the former 'loose object file' string.
> It also sidesteps any concerns about translating the `die` message differently for loose objects versus something else that has a real path.

No more:

```
 fatal: fsync error on 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor
```

But (Git 2.36+, Q2 2022):

```
 fatal: fsync error on 'path/to/file': Bad file descriptor
```

---

Plus, you can use trace2 to add more details, since Git 2.36 (Q2 2022): `trace2` code has been taught to report stats for `fsync` operations.

See [commit 9a49876](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a4987677d3f65e8cd93b9e77216f0f1026cd9b2) (30 Mar 2022) by [Neeraj Singh (`neerajsi-msft`)](https://github.com/neerajsi-msft).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe496dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe496dc5b9b527a85d381a3fc8e5f2fda9439842), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a4987677d3f65e8cd93b9e77216f0f1026cd9b2): add stats for `fsync` operations
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Neeraj Singh</sup>

> Add some global trace2 statistics for the number of `fsyncs` performed during the lifetime of a Git process.
>
> These stats are printed as part of `trace2_cmd_exit_fl,` which is presumably where we might want to print any other cross-cutting statistics.

You would see:

```
 fsync the_repository fsync/writeout-only  count_fsync_writeout_only
 fsync the_repository fsync/hardware-flush count_fsync_hardware_flush
```

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) now omits fsync-related trace2 entries when their values are all zero.

See [commit 3a251ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a251bac0d1a05b3dd9df45c45b40e2747829ca3) (18 Jul 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7c7719a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c7719ac0e24d61fc82a47502f05f11f8ddceec6), 27 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a251bac0d1a05b3dd9df45c45b40e2747829ca3): only include "`fsync`" events if we `git_fsync()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix the overly verbose trace2 logging added in [9a49876](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a4987677d3f65e8cd93b9e77216f0f1026cd9b2) ("`trace2`: add stats for fsync operations", 2022-03-30, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe496dc5b9b527a85d381a3fc8e5f2fda9439842)) (first released with v2.36.0).
>
> Since that change every single "`git`" command invocation has included these "data" events, even though we'll only make use of these with `core.fsyncMethod=batch`, and even then only have non-zero values if we're writing object data to disk.
> See [c0f4752](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0f4752ed2ffb89d10a9e469a83f089cc7e9df9d) ("`core.fsyncmethod`: batched disk flushes for loose-objects", 2022-04-04, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83937e9592832408670da38bfe6e96c90ad63521) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085)) for that feature.
>
> As we're needing to indent the `trace2_data_intmax()` lines let's introduce helper variables to ensure that our resulting lines (which were already too) don't exceed the recommendations of the CodingGuidelines.
> Doing that requires either wrapping them twice, or introducing short throwaway variable names, let's do the latter.
>
> The result was that e.g. "[`git version`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a251bac0d1a05b3dd9df45c45b40e2747829ca3/Documentation/git-version.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-version))</sup> would previously emit a total of 6 trace2 events with the `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT` target (version, start, `cmd_ancestry`, `cmd_name`, exit, atexit), but afterwards would emit 8. We'd emit 2 "data" events before the "exit" event.
>
> The reason we didn't catch this was that the trace2 unit tests added in [a15860d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a15860dca3f194bb87e2d6028264791a4cec031d) (`trace2`: t/helper/test-trace2, 2019-02-22, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7213a3d33f81035c0707b0f547462ecfa620223) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)) (trace2: t/helper/test-trace2, t0210.sh, t0211.sh, t0212.sh, 2019-02-22) would omit any "data" events that weren't the ones it cared about.
>
> Let's make the trace2 testing more strict, and further append any new events types we don't know about in "`t/t0212/parse_events.perl`".
> Since we only invoke the "`test-tool trace2`" there's no guarantee that we'll catch other overly verbose events in the future, but we'll at least notice if we start emitting new events that are issues every time we log anything with trace2's JSON target.
>
> We exclude the "`data_json`" event type, we'd otherwise would fail on both "win test" and "win+VS test" CI due to the logging added in [353d3d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/353d3d77f4fdd1582e3b60824deebca27c7b2790) ("`trace2`: collect Windows-specific process information", 2019-02-22, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7213a3d33f81035c0707b0f547462ecfa620223) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)).
> It looks like that logging should really be using `trace2_cmd_ancestry()` instead, which was introduced later in [2f732bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f732bf15e6dc9c2caf210784f180c6c059c570a) ("`tr2`: log parent process name", 2021-07-21, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f64eeab605b82b187b2dd1fc72492f434bad603) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4203212e360b25a1c69467b5a8437d45a373cac)), but let's leave it for now.
>
> The fix-up to [aaf8122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaf81223f48f710a3b9a64cc84fac93deed806b6) ("`unpack-objects`: use `stream_loose_object()` to unpack large objects", 2022-06-11, Git v2.38.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73b9ef6ab18fa7c9631f24eba0c67357067a1267) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dd64cb4d310986dd7b8ca7fff92f9b61e0bd21a)) is needed because we're changing the behavior of these events as discussed above.
> Since we'd always emit a "hardware-flush" event the test added in [aaf8122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaf81223f48f710a3b9a64cc84fac93deed806b6) wasn't testing anything except that this trace2 data was unconditionally logged.
> Even if "`core.fsyncMethod`" wasn't set to "batch" we'd pass the test.
>
> Now we'll check the expected number of "writeout" v.s.
> "flush" calls under "`core.fsyncMethod=batch`", but note that this doesn't actually test if we carried out the sync using that method, on a platform where we'd have to fall back to `fsync()` each of those "writeout" would really be a "flush" (i.e. a full `fsync()`).
>
> But in this case what we're testing is that the logic in "unpack-objects" behaves as expected, not the OS-specific question of whether we actually were able to use the "bulk" method.