# How to resolve Git fatal error 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor?

Tags: git, windows-10

I recently bought a new PC and setup the dev environment from scratch, including installing Git system for Windows (Git Bash).
My projects are stored on an external hard drive, mapped with the same letter as the old PC.
For this particular project, I'm only using Git to track changes, without pushing to any remote repository. Basically using `git add, git commit and git status`

Now on the new PC, when I try to `git add .`, I receive the following error:

```
fatal: fsync error on 'loose object file': Bad file descriptor
```

What's the cause and how to fix it? Could it be related to ssh certificate?

Comment: I confirm, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929881/git-fatal-fsync-error-on-sha1-file-bad-file-descriptor
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986318/2729928

Comment: Long story short: it was due to a change in permissions in a parent folder